# Error at installation type in oracle forms 12.2.1.4.0

Tags: oracleforms

I installed the web logic and trying to install the oracle forms and reports 12.2.1.4.0 version, but process halts at installation type without any error.

Can someone guide to resolve the issue.[image]

Comment: Select which of the two options you want and then click "Next >"?

Comment: @MT0, selected forms and reports Deployment and click next, but its not proceeding to next step, and highlighted in left top installation type in red color

Answer (score 0):

You can only do the full install on top of Fusion Middleware Infrastructure of the same version (12.2.1.4).  You cannot install on top of vanilla WLS.